# setVisibleXRangeMaximum() and setVisibleYRangeMaximum() not working in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am currently working with MPAndroidChart.I want to limit the number of rows and columns to be displayed.

To implement it, I've used **setVisibleXRangeMaximum()** and **setVisibleYRangeMaximum()** functions. But both of the above methods are not working.

I've set visibleXRangeMaximum and visibleYRangeMaximum values to 3. But the charts are showing all the values in both x-axis and y-axis.

**Code:**

```
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(3);
    lineChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(3, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);


    barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(3);
    barChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(3, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

### ScreenShot:

**In the below chart, all the values are shown whereas the expected output should contain 3 rows and 3 columns.**

[image: Chart Showing all the values]

Answer (score 9):

Just try to call setVisibleXRangeMaximum() after invalidating the chart.

Something like this :

```
lineChart.invalidate();
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(3);
```